# Can Dynamic Vtype validation Done(like below code) in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am new to extjs. I like to know,  Is it possible to do dynamic vtype validation like below code...

```
customRegEX = /^[a-z0-9]/i

customMsg = 'Must be an alphanumeric word'


function ConstructVtype(customRegEX,customMsg)
{
    var custExp = customRegEX;
    Ext.apply(Ext.form.VTypes, {
        AlphaNum: function(v,field) {   
            return /^[a-z0-9]/i.test(v); // instead of this code
            return custExp.test(v);
        },
        AlphaNumText: customMsg,
        AlphaNumMask: custExp
    });
}
```

But I am getting error (Object does not support this method) in the line `return custExp.test(v);`
since there is no method called test in the object(`custExp`)

Is it possible to typecast `custExp` to that object which hold the test method,

If the above point is possible means pls provide that object type and how to typecast ?
                                OR
Provide how can I achieve this functionality in different way.

hi "Alexander Gyoshev"  thanks for ur replay

if i do as per u recommended its working man but i need to change the regexp value dynamically by the textfield change, like the below code how can do this man

```
function ConstructVtype()
{   
    var customRegEX = this.customRegEX;  ////^[a-z0-9]/i,
    customMsg =this.customErrorMsg;

    Ext.apply(Ext.form.VTypes, {
        AlphaNum: function(v,field) {
            return customRegEX.test(v);
        },
        AlphaNumText: customMsg,
        AlphaNumMask: customRegEX
    }); 

}


var txt = new Ext.form.TextField({
 renderTo:Ext.getBody(),
  validator :ConstructVtype,
  fieldLabel: 'Telephone',
  name: 'Telephone',
  vtype:'AlphaNum',
  id:'test1',
  customRegEX:'/^[a-z0-9]/i',
  customErrorMsg:'Must be an alphanumeric word',
  width:240  

});

var txt2 = new Ext.form.TextField({
 renderTo:Ext.getBody(),
  validator :ConstructVtype,
  fieldLabel: 'Telephone',
  name: 'Telephone',
  vtype:'AlphaNum',
  id:'test2',
  customRegEX:'/^[a-zA-Z]/i',
  customErrorMsg:'Must be an alphabets',
  width:240  

});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The parameters of the function override the global ones. You can refactor the above code in the following way:

```
var customRegEX = /^[a-z0-9]/i,
    customMsg = 'Must be an alphanumeric word';


function ConstructVtype()
{
    Ext.apply(Ext.form.VTypes, {
        AlphaNum: function(v,field) {
            return customRegEX.test(v);
        },
        AlphaNumText: customMsg,
        AlphaNumMask: customRegEX
    });
}
```

Comment: hi alex thnks for ur reply ...i need a way out using this method ..pls check the question updated one ...

Answer (score 1):

```
var customRegEX = new RegExp('^[a-z0-9]',i);
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

[edited]

Of course I forgot to put '' around regexp string.

Comment: hey Mchl, thnk for ur reply man ..can u view my updated question... how can i use that common method for all textbox in the window or the form.

Answer (score 0):

I do some onfly function to pass value to vtype.
You can see in my topic.

[In ExtJS, Can I pass argument via vtype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878969/in-extjs-can-i-pass-argument-via-vtype)

Hope it help.