# In ExtJS, Can I pass argument via vtype?

Tags: extjs

I can't find the way to pass argument via vtype.
So I do some onfly vtype function.

```
var vtypeMaker = function(n){
    Ext.apply(Ext.form.VTypes, {
        myTest : function(v, o){
            console.debug(n); // <-- I can pass my custom value
            // do something
            // ...
            return myRegex.test(v);
        },
        myTestText : 'some message'
    });
}
```

And when I want to set vtype, I should call this function first.

```
vtypeMaker(10);
myTextfield.vtype = 'myTest';
```

It works but too long code.
Anyone has better idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to create your vtype dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the **validator** config to pass a custom validator function and use **createDelegate** to customize the parameters that will be sent to it:

```
var myValidator = function( value, custom ) {
    if ( /* value is valid */ ) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return 'Field value is not valid';
    }
};

new Ext.form.TextField({
    fieldLabel: 'A text field',
    validator: myValidator.createDelegate(null, [10], true);
});

new Ext.form.TextField({
    fieldLabel: 'Another text field',
    validator: myValidator.createDelegate(null, [14], true);
});
```

The custom parameters are set in the second parameter to **createDelegate**. Setting the third parameter to **true** will result in those custom parameters being appended to the parameters the function was called with (in this case, the field value).